# Eliminate $x$ from this system: $a \sec{ x} +b\tan{ x} +c = 0 $ and $ p \sec {x} +q\tan {x} + r = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

> Eliminate x from this system of equations:
>   $$\begin{align}
> a \sec{ x} +b\tan{ x} + c &= 0\\
> p \sec {x} +q\tan {x} + r &= 0
> \end{align}$$

I tried expressing the value of the trigonometric ratios from (2) and using that in (1).However all i get is 0=0

And how are such problems solved

And is there any standard procedure while eliminating trig equations

Hints please

Comment: Take $p$ times first question minus $a$ times second. You get $\tan x(bp-aq)+pc-ar=0$. That gives you an expression for $\tan x$. Do the same to get one for $\sec x$. Then use $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$.

Comment: We can use http://www.math-only-math.com/cross-multiplication-method.html to get $\sec x,\tan x$ directly and then utilize $$\sec^2x=\cdots$$

Comment: @ lab I think that was what i was missing<|>

Comment: So what is the final answer

Comment: I get$$r(b-a) -c(q-p) =0$$

Answer (score 1):

You have several methods to use. Here two.

1) A linear system $$aX+bY=-c\\pX+qY=-r$$
2) A quadratic equation in your (2) $$\frac {p}{\cos x}+q\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+r=0\\q\sin x+r\cos x=-p\\q\sin x+r\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=-p\\r^2(1-X^2)=(-(p+qX))^2=(p+qX)^2$$

Besides you can use other identities (in 1) and 2) you have use identities too!)